# Passing a managed object from private context to main context: it looses its related objects

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an `NSManagedObject` in a private context I have associated to a private queue. This `NSManagedObject` has a relationship to many other `NSManagedObject`s. I'd like to pass this former `NSManagedObject` with all its "nested" related objects to my main context without saving the private context, so I'm trying to do this:

```
__block NSManagedObjectID *privateObjectID = nil;

[privateContext performBlockAndWait: ^{
   MyEntity *privateMyEntity = [self createMyEntityInContext:privateContext];
   privateObjectID = [privateMyEntity valueForKeyPath:@"objectID"];
}];

if (privateObjectID != nil) {
   self.currentMyEntity = [mainContext objectWithID:privateObjectID];
}
```

But I find that the `self.currentMyEntity` has lost its related objects (its `NSSet` is empty).

However, if I save the private context before passing the managed object, then in `self.currentMyEntity` I get also the related objects:

```
__block NSManagedObjectID *privateObjectID = nil;

[privateContext performBlockAndWait: ^{
   MyEntity *privateMyEntity = [self createMyEntityInContext:privateContext];
   [self saveContext:privateContext];
   privateObjectID = [privateMyEntity valueForKeyPath:@"objectID"];
}];

if (privateObjectID != nil) {
   self.currentMyEntity = [mainContext objectWithID:privateObjectID];
}
```

Why? I don't want to save the object in the private context...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you should read the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html), and then you should reevaluate what you are trying to accomplish.

First, if you don't save the data anywhere, how do you expect a separate context to fetch anything about the object?  As far as that context is concerned, the object does not even exist?  What do they have in common?  The persistent store coordinator?  The persistent store?  If the entities they have in common don't have the data how are the different contexts supposed to exchange the data?

Second, you can't pass temporary object IDs between contexts and expect to use them.

Third, `objectWithID` always returns an object, even if that object does not exist, so you should only use it in certain situations.

If you don't want to save the object in the private context, then what do you want to do with it?

If you just want to pass it to the other context, then you can create the private context as a child context of the other context.  When you save from the private context, it will simply save the data up into that context, without saving to the database.